# Can't get the last two desired elements from the end of the list c++, mfc

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a list of figures that can be of different types derived from `Figure`. I want to find two elements of specific type coming from the end.

I have two iterators, when the first one find the element, the second one gets the value of the first iterator and continue towards beginning of the list.

It seams like the second iterator finds the right value, but it doesn't assign it to the object because in debug, I saw that iterator gets the right value, but `t2` doesn't. Cant understand that.

And the problem appears only when I have two elements in the list.

Here's the code:

```
            std::list<Figure*>::iterator it = pDoc->selectedFigures.end();
            std::list<Figure*>::iterator it2;

            if(it != pDoc->selectedFigures.begin())
            it--;
            else return;

            Point *t1 = new Point();
            Point *t2 = new Point();
            t1 = NULL;
            t2 = NULL;

            while(it != pDoc->selectedFigures.begin()){//finds the first point

                if((**it).type() == 1){
                    t1 = (Point*)(*it);
                    it2 = it;
                    break;
                }
                --it;
            }



            while(it2 != pDoc->selectedFigures.begin()){//finds the second point

                if((**it2).type()==1 && (*it2) != t1){
                    t2 = (Point*)(*it2);
                    break;
                }
                --it2;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example code, the problem is that `t1 == t2 (== NULL)`. Thus the condition in the second loop, `... && (*it2) != t1)` fails, and t2 is never set.

While I'm commenting, I suggest you use an enum (like FIGURE_TYPE_A) rather than hardcoding the type as 1.

Comment: The condition is met, I debugged the program and it does get to `t2 = (Point*)(*it2);` , so I guess that's not the problem. `t1=t2=NULL` is only at the beginning, but after the first point `t1` is found, it is not `null`..

Comment: Ah, good point. I was confused because your example allocates new Points to t1 and t2 and then (?) leaks that memory.

Comment: If you reach `t2 = (Point *)(*it2);` in the debugger, then t2 is being assigned. Add a printf to be 100% certain.

Outside of the test environment, the issue could still be the additional condition in the second loop. Since your list is composed of `Figure *`s, the "two Figures of type 1" in the list could be pointers to the same item.

Comment: Got it. When the list has 2 elements I find the second one with first iterator, but as in the while loop `it2 != list.begin()` the loop stops before `t1` is found. Thanks anyway :)